# Using TapGestureRecognizer Proper Syntax

Tags: swift, segue, xcode8, uitapgesturerecognizer

Can anyone help me out with this error? Not sure what it's asking for...

[TapGestureRecognizer Syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPCIV.png)

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapStart = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(tapped(gesture:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapStart)

    func tapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("It actually worked")
    }
}
```

my end goal seems like it should be fairly simple:

I want to segue to another view when the user taps anywhere on the screen. I'm creating a TapGestureRecognizer and for now am simply printing to the logs as the method so I can easily see if it works.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to copy and paste code into your questions. Images of code are no good here. Readers don't want to click links. They want to copy-paste your code. They want to edit your code. External images are double no good since they can disappear at any time and will not help future readers.

Comment: Oh! Now I know :P

Comment: check my answer  it will explain how to auto fix syntax error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `#selector(tapped(gesture:))` if you're on Swift 3. If you're on Swift 2 the selector will probably be `tapped(_:)` or something instead.

The compiler will ensure the existence of the symbol you're referencing when you use `#selector`. If you use a string and let the compiler create a Selector from the string literal, all you get is a warning like this. Same disadvantage goes for using the `Selector("funcname")` constructor.

Comment: Would I still start with 'action'?

Comment: Yes. `action:` is the parameter name that is part of the `UITapGestureRecognizer`'s constructor.

Comment: such as this - action:#selector(tapped(gesture:))     .

Comment: Now it's an error stating: "use of local variable 'tapped(gesture:)' before its declaration." Do I have to declare the new 'tapped' function elsewhere other than when I do just below? (As in the image above)

Comment: Short answer, no. No need to move it. Count your parentheses. Build your project. If the problem persists then you need to show more of your code.

Comment: Okay, so, I just realized that your `tapped` function is a local function, i.e. it's nested inside another function (`viewDidLoad`). It's not part of your class, it's part of its surrounding function. Move it out.

Comment: Oh wow that's great! It worked! Thanks so much, I'm brand new to swift and Xcode and I'm learning as I go. This just earned me a few hours of free time tonight still lol. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: Tested in Swift 3

Note: Syntax changed in Swift 3.

You can auto fix by holding **function+control+option+command+f** on your keyboard then Xcode will fix the issue for you.

Is nothing wrong with your code.Just, The way you using it.You,should placing your code like this...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapStart = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(tapped(gesture:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapStart)   
    }
    func tapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){ // func tapped(_:) this will works to
        print("Your in Right track mate")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Joe! I found that the issue in my case was the use of a local function (tapped) when it should have been outside of viewDidLoad() :)